# Pagination not display in adapter android

Tags: android

Why does my pagination not display data to adapters. Even though it was successfully loaded. Data is displayed but not below the last data but the first data disappears and changes to data page 2. Page 1 I limit with 10 items faithfully load the page, the fact that page 1 happened successfully loaded. When heading to page two the data was successfully loaded but did not appear on the `RecyclerView` so it still displays data 10 on page 1 earlier. When I wait for a while the data on the `RecyclerView` just appears page 2. But page 1 does not exist. So only page 2 is displayed. If I'm wrong in my coding, I've tried installing `NotifydataCahnge` but it didn't appear under page 1 earlier.

**adapter.java**

```
public class AdapterProduct extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProductBaru.HolerProduct> {

    List<ResultItem> resultItemList;
    Context mContext;

    public AdapterProductBaru(Context context, List<ResultItem> resultList){
        this.mContext = context;
        resultItemList = resultList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolerProduct onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_product, parent,false);
        return  new HolerProduct(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolerProduct holder, int position) {
            final ResultItem resultItem = resultItemList.get(position);

            holder.txt_id.setText(resultItem.getId());
            holder.txt_id_product_category.setText(resultItem.getIdProductCategory());
            holder.txt_id_currency.setText(resultItem.getIdCurrency());
            holder.txt_name_product.setText(resultItem.getName());
            holder.txt_description.setText(resultItem.getDescription());
            holder.txt_sku.setText(resultItem.getSku());
            holder.txt_stock.setText(resultItem.getStock());
            Locale localeID = new Locale("in", "ID");
            NumberFormat formatRupiah = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localeID);
            int Price_Capital = (Integer.parseInt(resultItem.getPriceCapital()));
            int Price_Sale = (Integer.parseInt(resultItem.getPriceSale()));

            if (Price_Capital == Price_Sale) {
                holder.txt_price_capital.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else  {
            holder.txt_price_capital.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            holder.txt_price_capital.setText(formatRupiah.format(Price_Capital));
            holder.txt_price_sale.setText(formatRupiah.format(Price_Sale));
            holder.txt_condition.setText(resultItem.getCondition());
            holder.txt_deliverable.setText(resultItem.getDeliverable());
            holder.txt_downloadable.setText(resultItem.getDownloadable());
            holder.txt_target_gender.setText(resultItem.getTargetGender());
            holder.txt_target_age.setText(resultItem.getTargetAge());
            holder.txt_visibility.setText(resultItem.getVisibility());
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(resultItem.getImage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
                    .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                    .into(holder.image);
            holder.txt_image.setText(resultItem.getImage());
            holder.txt_weight.setText(resultItem.getMetadata().getWeight());
            holder.txt_weight_value.setText(resultItem.getMetadata().getWeightValue());
            holder.txt_name_merchant.setText(resultItem.getMerchant().getName());
            holder.txt_id_company_category.setText(resultItem.getMerchant().getIdCompanyCategory());
            holder.txt_id_merchant.setText(resultItem.getMerchant().getId());
            holder.txt_location_merchant.setText(resultItem.getMerchant().getCity());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultItemList.size();
    }

    public class HolerProduct extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.btnclick)
        CardView btnclick;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_id)
        TextView txt_id;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_id_product_category)
        TextView txt_id_product_category;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_id_currency)
        TextView txt_id_currency;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_name_product)
        TextView txt_name_product;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_price_capital)
        TextView txt_price_capital;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_price_sale)
        TextView txt_price_sale;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_description)
        TextView txt_description;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_sku)
        TextView txt_sku;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_stock)
        TextView txt_stock;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_condition)
        TextView txt_condition;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_deliverable)
        TextView txt_deliverable;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_downloadable)
        TextView txt_downloadable;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_target_gender)
        TextView txt_target_gender;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_target_age)
        TextView txt_target_age;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_visibility)
        TextView txt_visibility;
        @BindView(R.id.image)
        ImageView image;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_image)
        TextView txt_image;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_image1)
        TextView txt_image1;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_image2)
        TextView txt_image2;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_image3)
        TextView txt_image3;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_image4)
        TextView txt_image4;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_weight_value)
        TextView txt_weight_value;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_weight)
        TextView txt_weight;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_name_merchant)
        TextView txt_name_merchant;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_id_merchant)
        TextView txt_id_merchant;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_id_company_category)
        TextView txt_id_company_category;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_location_merchant)
        TextView txt_location_merchant;
        @BindView(R.id.imagemerchant)
        ImageView imagemerchant;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_image_merchant)
        TextView txt_image_merchant;

        public HolerProduct(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    public void addListBarang(List<ResultItem> listBarang){

        for(ResultItem dataBarang  : listBarang)
        {
            resultItemList.add(dataBarang);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**LoadPage.java**

```
private void performPagaination(){

    pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mApiService.getResult(limit, page).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseProductBaru>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseProductBaru> call, Response<ResponseProductBaru> response) {

            if(response.body().getStatus()==200){

                List<ResultItem> dataList = response.body().getResult();
                adapterProductBaru.addListBarang(dataList);
                adapterProductBaru.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Page "+page+" is Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Toas Paging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseProductBaru> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("jajal" , t.getMessage()+ "list");
            ///progressBar.dismiss();
            pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Koneksi Internet Bermasalah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Recycler addScrollListener

```
  listAllProduct.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totallItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if(dy>0)
            {
                if(isLoading)
                {
                    if(totallItemCount > previous_total)
                    {
                        isLoading = false;
                        previous_total = totallItemCount;
                    }
                }

                if(!isLoading&&(totallItemCount-visibleItemCount)<=(pastVisibleItems+view_threshold))
                {
                    page++;
                    performPagaination();
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use List resultItemList; `ArrayList` instead of `List` here.
2. Second try to avoid `notifyDataSetChanged();` use for adding more items in to adapter this method:

```
public void addListBarang(List<ResultItem> listBarang) {
      final int positionStart = listBarang.size() + 1;
      resultItemList.addAll(listBarang);
      notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, resultItemList.size());
    }
```

Comment: Problem should be in adapter, somewhere you are replacing list instead of adding more items to it.